# How do I not commit my config.php file(completely ignore it, neither download or upload it) to Github when using VSCode?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have a config.php file on Github, I however have a different config.php file on my PC, how can I make Github completely ignore the file and make it both not download and upload it when I make a new commit?

I am using VSCode.

It is really annoying when it uploads the password of the config.php file to my private repo, is there a solution to that or should I just remove the config.php file from the folder when I want to make a new commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the file to your `.gitignore` file. Generally speaking, files that contain password or sensitive config information should be stored separately from your main git repository, for both security and so different workstations don't override each other.

For details, see the docs on [gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

Since the file was previously in the repository, run `git rm -r --cached config.php` to stop tracking it. Note that this file will still be present in past commits, so from a security perspective, if there is any sensitive information, you may want to consider changing passwords, etc.

Comment: It is added yet it still lets me stage the file and sync it from Github.

Comment: Added an extra step to take, since the file was previously committed.

Comment: But then I need type `git rm -r --cached config.php` every time I close and reopen VSCode, is there a way to automate it?

Comment: This is a one time action - you need to commit the change to your repo.

Answer (score 0):

Github is tied to git. It would be hard (impossible?) to commit your `config.php` to git but not upload it along with everything when you push your commits to GitHub.

So use [gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore). It will make git completely ignore the file.

Basically, create a text file in your git repo's root directory named `.gitignore` (no file extension).
The content of the file should be

```
config.php
```

or

```
path/to/config.php
```